# Can't make route.get work in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to recieve the information with the router in node, sorry I'm very new to node.js but this is all in the app.js file currently: (I just get a "cannot GET /api/ when going to localhost:1337/api

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql2');

var app = express();

var router = express.Router();
this.connection = null;

function startCon() {
    console.log("www");
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'users'
    })
}

function getAll(){
    console.log("bbb");
    this.connection = startCon();

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM user;', function (error, data) { 
        if(!error){
            console.log(data);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", error );
        }
    });
}

router.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log("lol");
    userDal.getAll(function(err, data){
        if(!err){
            res.json(data);
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

getAll();

app.listen(1337, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 1337');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have your `app` which listens to requests, and your `router` that handles the calls, but you are not tying them together.

you are missing this at the end of your code:

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the express demo](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html), you don't need the `express.Router()` call.

Change `router.get` to `app.get`

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log("lol");
    userDal.getAll(function(err, data){
        if(!err){
            res.json(data);
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: router indeed is not a must, you can do without. It has some advantages though